# 2 wifi's and one is not working

Tags: router

I have 2 routers at my home. The 2nd router was reset completely, and now it doesn't work.

It happened to me once and the tech guy told me that the 2nd router was configured somehow. He checked the IPs and the 2nd router had default IP. So he logged into the router and then he did something with DHCP. I think he turned it off and changed the IP numbers at the end of the IP. And then he did something else.

Can anyone help me figure out what he did with the router so that I can fix it?

Comment: is your second router acting as an access point or do you have two internet connections?  One for each router???

Comment: We have 2 wifi's so we do have 2 internet connections. So yes but they only edited the 2nd ( the one that has been reseted)

Comment: Do you have two separate internet lines coming into your home? Or just one and you're using two routers with it?

Comment: I only have 1 line

Comment: What make/model is the router are we talking about? Do you have a way of logging into the router to answer questions about how it's configured?

Comment: To be frank, you should probably reset it again and follow the steps on the router's quick start guide. If you don't have it anymore, you can almost always find a PDF version online.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably an issue with your ip ranges. Say router 1 gets internet from your ISP. That router is set to an ip range like 192.168.0.1. When you reset router 2 it changes it's ip range back to default for example 10.0.0.1. When you now connect router 2 to router 1 it doesn't recognize that device because it has an other ip range.

What you have to do is you have to get into the settings of router 2 and change the routers ip (static ip) to an ip that has the same format as router 1. (Here for example 192.168.0.5).

Answer (score 0):

You say you have one provider for the internet.  A typical setup would be to connect the internet to the first router and then connect the first router to the second router.
You would do that if you needed two wifi networks for better coverage or separation of concerns  (think iot on one wifi, laptops on another).

In order to make connecting one router to another work you have to configure the second router as an access point. This is done by turning off DHCP on the second router.
There is usually a network tab on the router page and you would turn off DHCP there.  I would also assign a static IP address outside the DHCP range so you can connect to it using the web interface if you ever need to change settings again.